# Incorrect Sum On Table Join

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am writing a query but i'm getting wrong result.Table are follows:

```
Tbl1(ProId, price,VId)
Tbl2(ProId, price, VId)
```

I have written this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.ProId, b.ProId,
    SUM(a.price) - SUM(b.price) AS TotalPro
FROM 
    tbl1 AS a 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl2 AS b ON a.ProId = b.ProId
WHERE 
    a.VId = '1234'
GROUP BY 
    a.ProId, b.ProId;
```

This query is returning an incorrect answer. What I have done is sum the price from table one and two separately and minus them the answer was fine. But when I join, I don't know why I am getting the wrong answer. ProId is same in both table, values are same.

Comment: Please share sample data and your desired results. We have no idea what you are expecting out of this incorrect sql so it's difficult to guide. Your sql is syntactically sound though, fwiw.

Comment: *why* is it incorrect? What results are you expected and what results did you get? What does your data look like? The expression you have is returning the right value, but your logic is going to be wrong. My guess, you have a cartesian product as you aren't aggregating separately. You likely think that the sum of `1`, `2`, and `3` is the same as the sum of `1`, `1`, `2`, `2`, `3`, and `3` (which, obviously, they are not).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want sth like below:

```
SELECT ProdId, SUM(price)
FROM (
  SELECT a.ProId,a.price
  FROM Tbl1 a
  WHERE a.VId='1234'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT b.ProdId, -b.price
  FROM Tbl2 b
  --WHERE b.VId ='1234' (?)
 ) sub
GROUP BY ProdId;
```

The issue with JOIN is you may have some rows that are summed multiple times.